# WordPress: Add custom style in <p>-tag in TinyMCE Editor

Tags: php, wordpress, tinymce, editor

I want to add a custom style to `<p>` tags in the TinyMCE editor.

I tried the following code. But it doesn't work with `<p>` tags. It works if I'm using `<span>` tags instead?!

Are there any limitations or is there something wrong with my code?

```
function my_mce_before_init_insert_formats( $init_array ) {  

    $style_formats = array(  
        array(  
            'title' => 'Lead',  
            'block' => 'p', 
            // 'block' => 'span',  <-- works
            'classes' => 'lead',
            'wrapper' => true,
        ),
    );  
    $init_array['style_formats'] = wp_json_encode( $style_formats );  
    
    return $init_array;  

}
```

Comment: My guess is, because p tag cannot exist inside another p tag it automatically ignores it as a valid block option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I found the solution.
The wrapper has to be `false` for paragraphs:

```
function my_mce_before_init_insert_formats( $init_array ) {  

    $style_formats = array(  
        array(  
            'title' => 'Lead',  
            'block' => 'p', 
            'classes' => 'lead',
            'wrapper' => false,
        ),
    );  
    $init_array['style_formats'] = wp_json_encode( $style_formats );  
    
    return $init_array;  

}
```